# Linked-list with nested classes: how can I use nested class type before it is declared?

Tags: c++, linked-list, declaration, nested-class

Ok, here's my problem, if a problem it is at all.

I'm building a linked list.
This linked list is composed of elements in form of a class.
Thus I have a class called, let's say, `linked_list` and a nested one called just `node`.

Obviously, the main class is meant for handling nodes and supply some functions to interact with them.

Here a draft of how it is supposed to look:

```
class linked_list
{
public:
    linked_list();
    ~linked_list();
    void setFirst(node *firstIn){first = firstIn;}
    node* getFirst(){return first};
    void forward();
    void forward(unsigned char);

private:
    node *first;
    node *current;

    class node
    {
    public:
        node();
        ~node();
        void function1();
        void function2();

    private:
        int various_data;
        node *next;
    };
};
```

Now, as you can imagine, the compiler gives me an error (two, actually) which tells me that the `node` type/class has not yet been declared, when I use it in the public section of the `linked_list` class to declare functions' arguments and return types.

I guess I could just invert `public:` and `private:` sections so that the declaration of the `node` class precedes its use, but this escamotage would annoy my (mild) OCD way too much for me to abide it.

Is there really no way other than inverting `public:` and `private:`?
It kills me!

Comment: Why did I get a -1? Because I didnt give an easy badge to the first who answered? Harsh audience, this place, for being meant to help...

Comment: -2? Poor kids, they wont get a prize.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **forward declaration** for that.

```
#include ...

class node;

public class linked_list {
...
}
```

Note:
This defeats the purpose of the inner class, because you are exposing it in your header. So, it is ok to do this for a simple exercise, but would be a bad architectural decision.

Comment: I hope this wont break any rules here at stackOverflow, but....I love you, man.  
My OCD thanks you.

Comment: @SergeBallesta What do you mean? I've just added the forward declaration and it works, it compiles and runs without a complaint. Anything I should be aware of that could break my program?

Comment: Ok, your edit clarifies SergeBallesta's (now disappeared) comment. So what? How else?

Comment: Either like this or as @Vlad from Moscow 
suggests.

Comment: Vlad's answer has been removed, God knows why, thus.....althought it's not a good answer, it still is the only one I got and I dont see why I shouldnt vote it.
Yet, it seems to nullify the purpose of nesting a class inside another one by exposing it....